# Callable struct in lambda expression

Tags: lambda, c++14, bind

I have the following MWE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <system_error>
#include <functional>

struct A
{
  A() : error() {}

  void operator()(const std::error_code& ec)
  {
    error = ec;
    std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
  }

  std::error_code error;
};

main()
{
  auto handler = A();
  std::error_code ec = std::error_code();

  auto func = [handler](const std::error_code& ec)
  {
    handler(std::error_code());
  };

  func(ec);
}
```

When I compile I get the following error message:

```
error: no match for call to '(const A) (const std::error_code&)' handler(ec);
```

Replacing this line with

```
std::bind<void>(handler, std::error_code());
```

does compile but it appears the function call operator of the struct A never gets called.

What is wrong here?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm not really familiar with C++ but your handler may not be called because your error code is 0 by default, thus the "then" branch is skipped in if(ec).

Comment: Sorry wrong MWE, just removing the if gives the same errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ lambdas are by default `const`, that is they cannot mutate captured variables. `A::operator()` is non-const, it mutates `A`. You can fix this by making the lambda mutable:

```
auto func = [handler] (const std::error_code& ec) mutable { /* ... */ };
```

Comment: Thanks this did the trick, I would never have guessed, the error message is completely unhelpful...

Comment: I'm pretty sure `auto handler = A();` is alright -- how could that `=` be part of a function declaration?